# error while using max() function in nested queries

Tags: pdo, mariadb

```
enter code here
```

'SELECT * FROM itemregister WHERE emailf IN (SELECT email from verify WHERE sno=MAX(sno))'

> I am getting error while using this query function like
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function" 
>   can any one help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than answer the question you asked, I will try to solve your problem with

```
SELECT  ir.*
    FROM ( 
        SELECT  email
            FROM  verify
            ORDER BY  sno DESC
            LIMIT  1 
         ) AS x
    JOIN  itemregister AS ir  ON x.email = ir.emailf
```